# SharePoint Security issue

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

I work for an IT company and I have come to know that besides all the security provided by SharePoint there is still document insecurity.  Like when I send someone an attachment in the network (in the company) there is no guarantee that the recipient will not misuse it by sending it outside the network. So if someone has any suggestions for me I'd appreciate it.

Comment: If the document is sent as an attachment on an email, SharePoint security is irrelevant. You may be able to limit what can be done with an individual document via IRM, but if a person has read access to a document in SharePoint, there's not a lot you can do to keep them from using the content inappropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eric - Omegacron is correct. Once a document is attached to an email it is out of your SharePoint installation forever. The best practice is to teach your users how to share links instead of documents. Some more extreme companies have accomplished this by disabling email attachments period. But in practice most companies will not do this and most people will keep on hitting "attach" instead of "link". A co-worker wrote a blog about this awhile back: http://info.easydynamics.com/blog/secure-messaging-storage-audit-trail

Answer (score 4):

Nothing is 100% secure, Because if a person who has right permission and he decided to misue of the documents than he can. But their are couple of things to try.

1. **Information Rights Management (IRM)** is a persistent file-level technology from Microsoft. It uses permissions and authorization to help prevent sensitive information from being printed, forwarded, or copied by unauthorized people. After permission for a document or message is restricted by using this technology, the usage restrictions travel with the document or email message as part of the contents of the file. [read complete details here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179103(v=office.15).aspx)
2. Enable the Auditing on your site, By that you will know about who is view/editing /downloading the docuemnts. [Configure audit settings for a site collection](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/sharepoint-help/configure-audit-settings-for-a-site-collection-HA102866204.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA102772739) and [View audit log reports](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/sharepoint-help/view-audit-log-reports-HA102772739.aspx)
3. Never send a document in attachment rather send the link to the document.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint is a content management platform. It enables storing document and data in multiple forms. It comes with security at various levels from

1. Web application
2. Site collection
3. Site
4. Library
5. Item level

Normally a user is give permissions based on his Role in the organization. If a user can misuse the role then there won't be any control (and its not the job of SharePoint).

To tackle things happening around the network you should use tool/setting available in your network devices. You can set rules in email servers to track down who is sending email to outside network. Or you can disable attachments sending to outside network